# Run selenium/cucumber test in linux machine in chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run selenium/cucumber Restfull API automation tests in a Jenkin's box which is a linux machine.
It runs locally on windows as I have chromedriver exe in my local machine.

I need a chrome bowser instance just to get the sessison Id and few cookies(for authentification/authorisation) after which I close browser and API testing begins.

I tried `com.lazerycode.selenium:driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin` but it fails to download the libraries(May be because of firewall issue).

What are other options?
Should I keep a copy of chromedriver.sh in my src directory?

Comment: "I tried ...plugin but it fails to download the libraries" Did you look at the Jenkins logs to see what happened?

Comment: I think it tries to download from URL http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_linux64.zip which is blocked in our organisation

Comment: The first thing I would try is to see if you can get an exception for the Jenkins box in your organization. If not, then you will need to keep a copy of all the binaries in your project.

Comment: Sure we will check.Thanks!